# How to format & write desired components of two arrays in a specified order to each line of a text file?

Tags: fortran

This is my code:

```
Program Arrays

Implicit none

Integer::i
Integer,parameter,dimension(3,4)::Fir_array=0,Sec_array=1

Open(Unit=15,File='Output.txt',Status='Unknown',Action='Readwrite')

   Do concurrent(i=1:3)

      Write(15,'(1x,i0,".",4(2x,i0,1x,i0))') i,Fir_array(i,:),Sec_array(i,:)

   End Do

Close(Unit=15,Status='Keep')

End Program Arrays
```

The content of `Output.txt` is:

```
1.  0 0  0 0  1 1  1 1
2.  0 0  0 0  1 1  1 1
3.  0 0  0 0  1 1  1 1
```

My intention with this code is to get this content in `Output.txt`:

```
1.  0 1  0 1  0 1  0 1
2.  0 1  0 1  0 1  0 1
3.  0 1  0 1  0 1  0 1
```

How to do that with do loops or implied do?

Comment: Why are you using concurrent do?

Comment: I can use any type of loops but i can not make format correctly. Do you have a sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

As usual, there is more than one way of going about this, but the first thing that came to my mind would be to place the desired components of `fir_array` and `sec_array` into a temporary array, in the desired order, and then print it.

```
! Add the following variables to your code:
integer, dimension(8) :: temp
integer :: d1

! Begin:
d1 = size(fir_array, dim=1)

do i = 1, d1
    temp([1,3,5,7]) = fir_array(i,:) !! If you're clever you can create a scheme to
    temp([2,4,6,8]) = sec_array(i,:) !! obtain the proper indices for arrays of any size.
    write(15, '(1x,i0,".",4(2x,i0,1x,i0))') i, temp
enddo
```

You get the output desired:

1. 0 1  0 1  0 1  0 1
2. 0 1  0 1  0 1  0 1
3. 0 1  0 1  0 1  0 1

Comment: How to do the same thing without temp array?

Comment: I'm not really sure, other than explicitly writing in which indices you want, like: `first(1), sec(1), first(2), sec(2), ....` . Is the temp array a problem?

Comment: It is not a problem but i want to know if there is a way with "original" arrays. That is all.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe using `advance='no'` in some way, but I don't think it's worth the effort. ;)

Comment: What you think about this solution:
`Write(15,'(1x,i0,".",4(2x,i0,1x,1x,i0))') i,(Fir_array(i,j),Sec_array(i,j),j=1,size(Fir_array,dim=2))`

Comment: @Judge_Dred I think that's pretty cool. Try replacing `4(2x,i0,1x,1x,i0)` with `*(2x,i0,2x,i0)` (notice the `*` and `2x` changes). The `*` prints the right number of items even if you change the length of the arrays.

Comment: @Judge_Dred That is the "unlimited repeat" format specifier. I like Intel's docs https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/678731.